# ClickOnce Update

Tags: c#, clickonce

**Summary**

We have a C# application which we would like to deploy using ClickOnce. It's meant to be used by different schools ( each school is a seperate client ). The problem we're encountering is this:

- We'd like to have different versions, with special features for each school ( if requested ), for example: School 1 wants to have an extra field in which they could add some statistics, while School 2 doesn't want to have that feature at all. We'd like to cover this with versioning.
- How we might differentiate for which school is checking for an update, is to add the update check programmatically in the Login section, and then pass the session token of the login as a query parameter, and work out the re-route ( URL for the File Hosting server ) on the back-end side, dependent on the user's token. Only thing here is that I don't know how i would pass the session token taken from the first part of the Login method, as a query parameter to the update check for the ClickOnce.

Is there any way ( function/method/workaround ) on the programmatic side, in which i can pass that string, and then have it be appended to the Deployment URL before it gets sent to the server?

Comment: AFAIK ClickOnce is outdated. I would recommend taking a look at the new-ish [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview)-Format. Especially as ClickOnce was never especially good (i.e. easy to work with).

Comment: seems like you'd just store something in your database (version#?) which is connected to the login.  Why bother with a session token?

Comment: The typical way of delivering different functionality to different clients is through a web app, not a desktop app.

Comment: 1) Will check it out

Comment: 2) I will have a special hash in the database, but to know which route to redirect the user's Update to ( ex. user in school 1 would have to get update from //dropbox.com/school_1, user in school 2 from //dropbox.com/school_2 ), that's why I would send the session token, to know which school the user is from

Comment: 3) We know, but the application is used for printing diplomas, end of the school year grade cards, etc. and the fact that when we started making it ( a year ago ), we didn't have in plan to add multiple functionalities and clients